# Как сохранить DataGridView в бд при подходе DataBaseFirst?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

После создания WinForms(.Net Framework) и подключения при помощи EF к СУБД MSSQL , используя DatabaseFirst подход, создал DataGridView , который подключился к DataSource , выгрузка данных сработала на ура и всё бд отобразилось , однако, после создания кнопки для сохранения данных в СУБД понял, что для этого используется сгенерированный DataSet и TableAdapter , в которых есть методы AcceptChanges и Update, но почему-то при использовании данной кнопки данные не сохраняются и не изменяются.

```
        this.*сгенерированное_название_датасета*DataSet.AcceptChanges();
        this.*сгенерированное_название_из_СУБД*Adapter.Update(*сгенерированное_название_датасета*DataSet);
```

Итак, как мне сохранить все данные из DataGridView в таком случае?

Comment: DataSet и Entity Framework - две **разные** технологии. Используйте либо то, либо другое. / .Net Framework давно умер. Забудьте про него. В данный момент актуален .NET 6. Создавайте все проекты под него.

Comment: [Databinding with WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms) - посмотрите это, если хотите именно EF использовать.